# How to Set Quota for Google Maps API from external site?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-console

i'am trying to figure, how to set Google Maps API quota (specific : Geocoding API) from external site ? i want to build my own dashboard for set the quota, not using Google Cloud Console for daily operations.

PS : i need to set a certain quota on certain days.

I was searching for any tutorial & api on Google Cloud Console, i just found as far as enabling / disabling the API, not setting the quota

i expect some of tutorial or some kind explanation how to reach that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reasonable request but...

To my knowledge (!), there is no public API that would permit you to manage quotas (for **any** Google service) programmatically and thus through your own dashboards.

Found some references for you on controlling this using Google's Console:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing
- https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage